# Can someone look at my code and tell me whats wrong?

Tags: java

So my requirement is to display a message showing yours and your friend's initials in lower case (ie. "mf and js are friends").

Here's my code

```
String myFullName = "Daniel Camarena";
String friendsFullName = "John Smith";

System.out.println(   myFullName.toLowerCase().charAt(0) 
                    + myFullName.toLowerCase().charAt(7)
                    + " and " 
                    + friendsFullName.toLowerCase().charAt(0)
                    + friendsFullName.toLowerCase().charAt(5)
                    + " are friends." );
```

The output I get is 
`199 and js are friends.`

Comment: Your question title should describe your specific problem/question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
myFullName.toLowerCase().charAt(0) + myFullName.toLowerCase().charAt(7)
```

are working on ascii integer value and hence 199

The reason strings addition works for the second name is because that is part of the string formed due to this:

```
                + " and "
```

Quick fix, add an empty string at start

```
System.out.println("" +   myFullName.toLowerCase().charAt(0) 
                    + myFullName.toLowerCase().charAt(7)
                    + " and " 
                    + friendsFullName.toLowerCase().charAt(0)
                    + friendsFullName.toLowerCase().charAt(5)
                    + " are friends." );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   System.out.println(  "" + myFullName.toLowerCase().charAt(0)                       + myFullName.toLowerCase().charAt(7)
                + " and " 
                + friendsFullName.toLowerCase().charAt(0)
                + friendsFullName.toLowerCase().charAt(5)
                + " are friends." );
```

Append the blank string to convert it to String and then it will start doing concanetation . As '+' is overloaded operator it is doing addition till it encounters String.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code :

```
String myFullName = "Daniel Camarena";
    String friendsFullName = "John Smith";

    String[] arrMyFullName = myFullName.toLowerCase().split(" ");
    String[] arrFriendsFullName = friendsFullName.toLowerCase().split(" ");

    String message = "";
    for(String s : arrMyFullName)
        message += s.charAt(0);
    message += " and ";

    for(String s : arrFriendsFullName)
        message += s.charAt(0);
    message += " are friends.";

    System.out.println( message );
```

Above code also work if name is more than 2 words.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
    System.out.println(  "" +  myFullName.toLowerCase().charAt(0)
            + myFullName.toLowerCase().charAt(7)
            + " and "
            + friendsFullName.toLowerCase().charAt(0)
            + friendsFullName.toLowerCase().charAt(5)
            + " are friends." );
```

Answer (score 0):

With this one you can have any name of friends. Instead of correcting the index which differs for each name.

```
        String myFullName = "Daniel Camarena";
        String friendsFullName = "John Smith";

        String[] myNameSplit = myFullName.split(" ");
        String myFirstInitial = String.valueOf(myNameSplit[0].charAt(0));
        String myLastInitial = String.valueOf(myNameSplit[1].charAt(0));

        String[] myFriendNameSplit = friendsFullName.split(" ");
        String myFriendFirstInitial = String.valueOf(myFriendNameSplit[0].charAt(0));
        String myFriendLastInitial = String.valueOf(myFriendNameSplit[1].charAt(0));

        System.out.println(myFirstInitial+myLastInitial + " and " + myFriendFirstInitial+myFriendLastInitial+ " are friends");
```

Answer (score 0):

It is adding ASCII value of d and c in output to avoid that do as following.

```
String myFullName = "Daniel Camarena";
        String friendsFullName = "John Smith";

        System.out.println(   myFullName.toLowerCase().charAt(0) 
                    +""+ myFullName.toLowerCase().charAt(7)
                    + " and " 
                    + friendsFullName.toLowerCase().charAt(0)
                    + friendsFullName.toLowerCase().charAt(5)
                    + " are friends." );
```